# summing inputs with class and id with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to sum inputs in my table.

I am trying to sum weekly totals (Monday, Thursday, Wednesday), and also trying to sum the daily hours (overtime, public holiday) when refreshing the page while the user type his or her hours worked. If the user change any of their inputs, it must change the totals as well.

I am able to get the javascript to sum weekly, but it doesn't want to calculate the daily hours, as well as the other way around.

This is what I have tried so far:

```js
$(document).on("change", ".monday", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".monday").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $(".totaltimemonday").val(sum);
});

$(document).on("change", ".normaltime", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".normaltime").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $("normaltimetotal").val(sum);
});
```

```html
<!-- This line is added to the snippet to allow it to access jQuery functions.
     It is not part of the original code. -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="timesheet_create" style="100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Mon</th>
        <th>Tue</th>
        <th>Wed</th>
        <th>Thu</th>
        <th>Fri</th>
        <th>Sat</th>
        <th>Sun</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Normal time</th>
        <td><input name="normal_monday" value="" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="monday text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="normaltime"></td>
        <td><input name="normal_thus" value="" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="normaltime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="normaltime"></td>
        <td><input name="normal_wensn" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="normaltime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="normaltime"></td>
        <td><input name="normal_thu" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="normaltime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="normaltime"></td>
        <td><input name="normal_fri" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="normaltime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="normaltime"></td>
        <td><input name="normal_sat" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="normaltime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="normaltime"></td>
        <td><input name="normal_sun" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="normaltime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="normaltime"></td>
        <td><input name="normaltimetotal" value="" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="normaltimetotal text-center" type="text" size="2" id="totaltime1"></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <th>Weekly overtime hourly Rate x 1.5</th>
        <td><input name="weekly_monday" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="monday text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="weeklyovertime"></td>
        <td><input name="weekly_thus" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="weeklyovertime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="weeklyovertime"></td>
        <td><input name="weekly_wenso" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="weeklyovertime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="weeklyovertime"></td>
        <td><input name="weekly_thu" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="weeklyovertime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="weeklyovertime"></td>
        <td><input name="weekly_fri" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="weeklyovertime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="weeklyovertime"></td>
        <td><input name="weekly_sat" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="weeklyovertime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="weeklyovertime"></td>
        <td><input name="weekly_sun" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="weeklyovertime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="weeklyovertime"></td>
        <td><input name="weeklyovertimetotal" value="" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="weeklyovertimetotal text-center" type="text" size="2" id="totaltime2" readonly></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Saturday overtime hourly Rate x 1.5</th>
        <td><input name="monday" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="saterdayovertime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="saterdayovertime"></td>
        <td><input name="thus" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="saterdayovertime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="saterdayovertime"></td>
        <td><input name="wens" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="saterdayovertime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="saterdayovertime"></td>
        <td><input name="thu" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="saterdayovertime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="saterdayovertime"></td>
        <td><input name="fri" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="saterdayovertime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="saterdayovertime"></td>
        <td><input name="saterday_sat" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="saterdayovertime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="saterdayovertime"></td>
        <td><input name="sun" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="saterdayovertime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="saterdayovertime"></td>
        <td><input name="saterdayovertimetotal" value="" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="saterdayovertimetotal text-center" type="text" size="2" id="totaltime3" readonly></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Sunday time B hourly Rate x 1.0</th>
        <td><input name="monday" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sundayovertimeb text-center" type="text" size="2" id="sundayovertimeb"></td>
        <td><input name="thus" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sundayovertimeb text-center" type="text" size="2" id="sundayovertimeb"></td>
        <td><input name="wens" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sundayovertimeb text-center" type="text" size="2" id="sundayovertimeb"></td>
        <td><input name="thu" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sundayovertimeb text-center" type="text" size="2" id="sundayovertimeb"></td>
        <td><input name="fri" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sundayovertimeb text-center" type="text" size="2" id="sundayovertimeb"></td>
        <td><input name="sat" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sundayovertimeb text-center" type="text" size="2" id="sundayovertimeb"></td>
        <td><input name="sunb_sun" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sundayovertimeb text-center" type="text" size="2" id="sundayovertimeb"></td>
        <td><input name="sundayovertimebtotal" value="" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sundayovertimebtotal text-center" type="text" size="2" id="totaltime4" readonly></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Sunday overtime NB hourly Rate x 2.0</th>
        <td><input name="monday" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="monday text-center" type="text" size="2" id="sundayovertimenb"></td>
        <td><input name="thus" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sundayovertimenb text-center" type="text" size="2" id="sundayovertimenb"></td>
        <td><input name="wens" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sundayovertimenb text-center" type="text" size="2" id="sundayovertimenb"></td>
        <td><input name="thu" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sundayovertimenb text-center" type="text" size="2" id="sundayovertimenb"></td>
        <td><input name="fri" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sundayovertimenb text-center" type="text" size="2" id="sundayovertimenb"></td>
        <td><input name="sat" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sundayovertimenb text-center" type="text" size="2" id="sundayovertimenb"></td>
        <td><input name="sunnb_sun" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sundayovertimenb text-center" type="text" size="2" id="sundayovertimenb"></td>
        <td><input name="sundayovertimenbtotal" value="" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sundayovertimenbtotal text-center" type="text" size="2" id="totaltime5" readonly></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Public holiday time hourly Rate x 1.0</th>
        <td><input name="ph_monday" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="publicholidaytime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="monday"></td>
        <td><input name="ph_thus" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="publicholidaytime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="publicholidaytime"></td>
        <td><input name="ph_wens" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="publicholidaytime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="publicholidaytime"></td>
        <td><input name="ph_thu" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="publicholidaytime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="publicholidaytime"></td>
        <td><input name="ph_fri" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="publicholidaytime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="publicholidaytime"></td>
        <td><input name="ph_sat" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="publicholidaytime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="publicholidaytime"></td>
        <td><input name="ph_sun" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="publicholidaytime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="publicholidaytime"></td>
        <td><input name="publicholidaytimetotal" value="" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="publicholidaytimetotal text-center" type="text" size="2" id="totaltime6" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <th>Public holiday overtime hourly Rate x 2</th>
        <td><input name="pho_monday" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="photime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="monday"></td>
        <td><input name="pho_thus" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="photime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="photime"></td>
        <td><input name="pho_wens" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="photime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="photime"></td>
        <td><input name="pho_thu" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="photime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="photime"></td>
        <td><input name="pho_fri" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="photime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="photime"></td>
        <td><input name="pho_sat" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="photime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="photime"></td>
        <td><input name="pho_sun" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="photime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="photime"></td>
        <td><input name="photimetotal" value="" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="photimetotal text-center" type="text" size="2" id="totaltime7" readonly></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Unpaid leave/Absent shifts</th>
        <td><input name="ul_monday" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="upaid text-center" type="text" size="2" id="monday"></td>
        <td><input name="ul_thus" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="upaid text-center" type="text" size="2" id="upaid"></td>
        <td><input name="ul_wens" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="upaid text-center" type="text" size="2" id="upaid"></td>
        <td><input name="ul_thu" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="upaid text-center" type="text" size="2" id="upaid"></td>
        <td><input name="ul_fri" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="upaid text-center" type="text" size="2" id="upaid"></td>
        <td><input name="ul_sat" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="upaid text-center" type="text" size="2" id="upaid"></td>
        <td><input name="ul_sun" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="upaid text-center" type="text" size="2" id="upaid"></td>
        <td><input name="upaidtotal" value="" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="upaidtotal text-center" type="text" size="2" id="totaltime8" readonly></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Authorised short time Hours</th>
        <td><input name="ast_monday" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="AuthorisedShorttime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="monday"></td>
        <td><input name="ast_thus" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="AuthorisedShorttime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="AuthorisedShorttime"></td>
        <td><input name="ast_wens" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="AuthorisedShorttime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="AuthorisedShorttime"></td>
        <td><input name="ast_thu" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="AuthorisedShorttime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="AuthorisedShorttime"></td>
        <td><input name="ast_fri" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="AuthorisedShorttime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="AuthorisedShorttime"></td>
        <td><input name="ast_sat" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="AuthorisedShorttime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="AuthorisedShorttime"></td>
        <td><input name="ast_sun" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="AuthorisedShorttime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="AuthorisedShorttime"></td>
        <td><input name="AuthorisedShorttimetotal" value="" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="AuthorisedShorttimetotal text-center" type="text" size="2" id="totaltime9" readonly></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Non Authorised short time Hours</th>
        <td><input name="nast_monday" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="nonAuthorisedShorttime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="monday"></td>
        <td><input name="nast_thus" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="nonAuthorisedShorttime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="nonAuthorisedShorttime"></td>
        <td><input name="nast_wens" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="nonAuthorisedShorttime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="nonAuthorisedShorttime"></td>
        <td><input name="nast_thu" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="nonAuthorisedShorttime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="nonAuthorisedShorttime"></td>
        <td><input name="nast_fri" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="nonAuthorisedShorttime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="nonAuthorisedShorttime"></td>
        <td><input name="nast_sat" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="nonAuthorisedShorttime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="nonAuthorisedShorttime"></td>
        <td><input name="nast_sun" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="nonAuthorisedShorttime text-center" type="text" size="2" id="nonAuthorisedShorttime"></td>
        <td><input name="nonAuthorisedShorttimetotal" value="" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="nonAuthorisedShorttimetotal text-center" type="text" size="2" id="totaltime10" readonly></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Study Leave Days</th>
        <td><input name="stl_monday" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="studyleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="monday"></td>
        <td><input name="stl_thus" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="studyleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="studyleave"></td>
        <td><input name="stl_wens" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="studyleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="studyleave"></td>
        <td><input name="stl_thu" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="studyleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="studyleave"></td>
        <td><input name="stl_fri" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="studyleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="studyleave"></td>
        <td><input name="stl_sat" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="studyleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="studyleave"></td>
        <td><input name="stl_sun" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="studyleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="studyleave"></td>
        <td><input name="studyleavetotal" value="" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="studyleavetotal text-center" type="text" size="2" id="totaltime11" readonly></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Annual Leave Days</th>
        <td><input name="al_monday" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="annualleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="monday"></td>
        <td><input name="al_thus" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="annualleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="annualleave"></td>
        <td><input name="al_wens" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="annualleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="annualleave"></td>
        <td><input name="al_thu" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="annualleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="annualleave"></td>
        <td><input name="al_fri" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="annualleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="annualleave"></td>
        <td><input name="al_sat" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="annualleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="annualleave"></td>
        <td><input name="al_sun" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="annualleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="annualleave"></td>
        <td><input name="annualleavetotal" value="" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="annualleavetotal text-center" type="text" size="2" id="totaltime12" readonly></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Sick Leave Days</th>
        <td><input name="sl_monday" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sickleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="monday"></td>
        <td><input name="sl_thus" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sickleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="sickleave"></td>
        <td><input name="sl_wens" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sickleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="sickleave"></td>
        <td><input name="sl_thu" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sickleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="sickleave"></td>
        <td><input name="sl_fri" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sickleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="sickleave"></td>
        <td><input name="sl_sat" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sickleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="sickleave"></td>
        <td><input name="sl_sun" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sickleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="sickleave"></td>
        <td><input name="sickleavetotal" value="" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="sickleavetotal text-center" type="text" size="2" id="totaltime13" readonly></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Family Respon Leave Days</th>
        <td><input name="frl_monday" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="familyresponleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="monday"></td>
        <td><input name="frl_thus" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="familyresponleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="familyresponleave"></td>
        <td><input name="frl_wens" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="familyresponleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="familyresponleave"></td>
        <td><input name="frl_thu" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="familyresponleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="familyresponleave"></td>
        <td><input name="frl_fri" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="familyresponleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="familyresponleave"></td>
        <td><input name="frl_sat" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="familyresponleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="familyresponleave"></td>
        <td><input name="frl_sun" value=""  onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="familyresponleave text-center" type="text" size="2" id="familyresponleave"></td>
        <td><input name="familyresponleavetotal" value="" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="familyresponleavetotal text-center" type="text" size="2" id="totaltime14" readonly></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Total:</th>
        <td><input name="total_mon" readonly value="" onblur="findTotals()" class="totaltimemonday text-center" id="totalmonday" type="text" size="2" ></td>
        <td><input name="total_thus" readonly value="" onblur="findTotals()" class="totaltimethus text-center" id="totalthus" type="text" size="2" ></td>
        <td><input name="total_wens" readonly value="" onblur="findTotals()" class="totaltimewens text-center" id="totalwens" type="text" size="2" ></td>
        <td><input name="total_thu" readonly value="" onblur="findTotals()" class="totaltimethu text-center" id="totalthu" type="text" size="2" ></td>
        <td><input name="total_fri" readonly value="" onblur="findTotals()" class="totaltimefri text-center" id="totalfri" type="text" size="2" ></td>
        <td><input name="total_sat" readonly value="" onblur="findTotals()" class="totaltimesat text-center" id="totalsat" type="text" size="2" ></td>
        <td><input name="total_sun" readonly value="" onblur="findTotals()" class="totaltimesun text-center" id="totalsun" type="text" size="2" ></td>
        <td><input name="totaltimetotal" readonly value="" class="totaltimetotal text-center" id="totaltimetotal" type="text" size="2" ></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: IDs are meant to be unique, you should use class names instead of IDs.

Comment: Your HTML has `id="monday"` (wrong as you have more than one)! But your javascript is addressing `.monday` which is  how you address a class !?!?!

Comment: Your HTML refers to functions `calculateTotal` and `findTotals`, which aren't defined here.

Comment: @mc10 Maybe, but you should NOT edit things into the question!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't think I did? I just changed it into snippet form, which requires that we add a line of jQuery for it to run.

Comment: `$(".normaltimetotal")` instead of `$("normaltimetotal")`

Comment: Right you added `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` If you believe that is required say so in an answer

Comment: You should not use same id for more than one element **ids should be unique**

Comment: @RiggsFolly Added a comment to explain why it's necessary only for the snippet.

Comment: I've tried so many things to get it work i forgot to make thi id unique. If i add # to the javascript to use the class name, it does not work at all. Is there an easier way to calulate the totals.